# How can I get access to Discord API guild's channel actions?

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, discord

I am new to Javascript. Now I am working on a Chrome Extension.
I need to realize ability to create a Discord guild channel by clicking link in the Chrome Extension.

I am successfully signing in via Discord in the Chrome Extension and getting access token. After this I'm trying to create channel, but always getting 401 Unauthorized.

But where I do GET request to show user guilds (/users/@me/guilds) it works, but when trying to GET channels (/users/@me/channels) I receiving only 401 unauthorized..

Could anybody explain what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you in advance)

Here is my code:
(scope from first request: guilds.join, identify, guilds, email, connections, messages.read, bot, rpc, rpc.api)

```
$("#discord_sign_in").click(function () {
    chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(
        {'url': 'https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=*hidden*&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fgnbkehnofikpgioaajgmejnkihdkpiap.chromiumapp.org%2Fsettings%2Findex.html&response_type=code&scope=guilds.join%20identify%20guilds%20email%20connections%20messages.read%20bot%20rpc%20rpc.api',
        'interactive': true},
        function(redirect_url) { 
            console.log('Authorization success'); 
            console.log(redirect_url);
            // var redirect_url = redirect.replace("#", "?");
            var url = new URL(redirect_url);
            var code = url.searchParams.get("code");
            console.log(code);

            localStorage.setItem('discord_code', code);

            console.log('get new code: ' + localStorage.getItem('discord_code'));

        });
    });


$("#discord_sign_in_bot").click(function() {
    $.ajax( {
        url: 'https://discordapp.com/api/v6/oauth2/token',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { grant_type: 'authorization_code',
                scope: 'bot',
                client_id: 'localStorage.getItem('client_id')',
                client_secret: 'localStorage.getItem('client_secret')',
                code: localStorage.getItem('discord_code'),
                permissions: 8,
                redirect_uri: 'https://gnbkehnofikpgioaajgmejnkihdkpiap.chromiumapp.org/settings/index.html' },
        success: function( response ) {
            console.log("Successfully authorized bot (Discord).")
            console.log(response);
            console.log("access_token: " + response['access_token']);
            localStorage.setItem('discord_token', response['access_token']);
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("Failed to bot authorization (Discord).")
        }
    } );
});

$("#discord_create_channel").click(function() {
    $.ajax( {
        url: 'https://discordapp.com/api/v6/guilds/594100687508340776/channels/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { name: 'Test-channel-5' },
        beforeSend : function( xhr ) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader( "Authorization", "Bot " + localStorage.getItem('discord_token'));
        },
        success: function( response ) {
            console.log("Successfully created guild channel (Discord).")
        },
        error: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            console.log("Failed to create guild channel (Discord).")
        }
    } );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `/users/@me/channels` is not for creating a guild channel, but for creating a DM channel. Also you shouldn't send a GET request to `/users/@me/channels`, but a POST request as the documentation says. At this moment there is no possibility to create a guild channel with Discord oauth2 so unfortunately you won't be able to procees your extension.

Here are the Discord documentations:
https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user